# Installing Spark/Zeppelin on Standalone node

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a Cloudera cluster which is being managed by an admin team. However there is no Zeppelin installed in the cluster.

I would like to install Zeppelin on a separate node and connect with the Cloudera cluster?

Is it feasible to install zeppelin on a node which is not part of the cluster and submit spark jobs to it?

Any reference is really appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, It's Possible. Remember you should set Yarn (Spark Master) address and other settings properly in your interpreter settings.

Answer (score 2):

Zeppelin is just another Spark client.

For example, on the machine that you want to use Zeppelin on, you should first make sure that spark shell and spark submit work as expected, then Zeppelin configurations become much easier

An easy way to manage that would be to have the admins use Cloudera Manager to install Spark (and Hive and Hadoop) client libraries into this standalone node, then I assume they give you SSH access, or you tell them how to install it